# Javascript: How to call on different objects in array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to understand how to pull a specific item from the code below.

```
var snake = [[{x : 20, y : 30}],[{x : 40, y: 50}]];
```

Coming from python I found this to be useful when dealing with for loops to have all my objects in an array within an array.

Say for instance I want to pull the first `x:` value from the first object container. I thought `snake[0][0].x` would return `20`, and `snake[1][1].y`would return `50`. but instead I receive: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

```js
var snake = [[{x : 20, y : 30}],[{x : 40, y: 50}]];
snake[0][0].x;
snake[1][1].y;
```

I'm new to JavaScript, trying to understand why this doesn't work and if there is a way to write this so that it may. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The second sub-array has only one item, thus `[1][1]` will be `undefined`, use `[1][0]` instead

Comment: `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` Can't reproduce this one, see snippet - error occurs on the `.y` line

Comment: I'm voting to close. This seems more a typo problem.

Comment: you were right. I had so many variables referencing this one object.. tons of pops and unshifting. I got it to work. Thank you very much for making me question how I wrote this. I thought that was how JS would work as well and I'm happy to know that it does. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is specifically with your second statement, `snake[1][1]`.

The second object would be referenced with `snake[1][0]`.

The first index refers to the position in the outermost array, with each subsequent index referring to the next inner level of array. Since each of your inner arrays only have one value (the objects within them), any index other than 0 will return an undefined error.

You can verify this by using `snake[1][0].y`, which returns 50, as you'd expect.

Comment: I have tried to change that to `snake[1][0]` but I still receive `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` I have no idea why. I need them to be separate objects in separate arrays because I produce multiple x and y values throughout the program. The idea being there will be multiple snakes. But I cannot get this to work.

Comment: I had so many variables referencing this one object.. tons of pops and unshifting. I got it to work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, for reference you don't need a 2d array here, you could format it as described in VeP's answer.

Comment: Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since snake is an array with two elements, with each element being an array containing a single object, then you should be able to do the following:

```
snake[0][0].x
snake[1][0].x
```

You could of course declared snake as:

```
var snake = [{x : 20, y : 30},{x : 40, y: 50}];
```

and then you could address it using:

```
snake[0].x
snake[1].x
```